# Json_valid function as a constraint in mariadb

Tags: mysql, mariadb

There are different ways to create constraint in mariadb. We can either create them when creating the tables or after that. For example, the json_valid function could be defined in 3 different ways:

1) CREATE TABLE t2 (
  j JSON 
  CHECK (JSON_VALID(j))
);

2) after table creation: "Alter table t2 add check(json_valid(j))"

3) "alter table t2 add constraint something check(json_valid(j))"

Which one is preferable and why?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why would you need to check that the JSON document is valid? By using the `JSON` data type, that prevents any invalid JSON document from being inserted anyway. It would be important if you were storing JSON data in a `TEXT` column.

Comment: Can you provide any resource for this claim? if mariadb itself checks the json validation, what is the usability of this CHECK(json_valid(j))?

Comment: Oh, you're using mariadb. I think they just use a TEXT or VARCHAR column, which means they do allow invalid JSON. This is confirmed in their own blog from 2017: https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/json-with-mariadb-10-2/ How disappointing. Well, this is why I don't use MariaDB.

Comment: Yes Mariadb stores it as a TEXT. Ya maybe mariadb is not a wise choice. By the way, thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are no `INSERTs` before the `ALTER`, they are all equivalent.

Doing everything in the `CREATE TABLE` is probably a tiny bit faster.